# Is it "with different alcoholic contents" or "of different alcoholic contents"?

Tags: grammar

Should we use the preposition "with" or should we use the preposition "of"? By "alcoholic content", I mean level or total amount of alcohol. I am not sure I have heard "with different alcoholic contents", but I am not sure why it would be wrong.

For example:

> I drank a lot of beer with different alcoholic contents throughout my
>   life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you never use the word **contents** for **alcohol. Strength,** maybe?
That said, your sentence should look something like this: (I've also changed the sentence to make it more elegant.)

> I've tried beers of **different/varying** alcoholic strength throughout my life.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I think the original poster means “alcohol **content**” (not *contents*).